# jquery update table from mysql db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have a table with 26rows and 8 cols

if you click on one of the tables td's it sets the bgcolor to red and updates a mysqldb with the tables row and col you clicked....

how do i make jquery get that data from mysql and set clicked row/col bgcolor to red

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#test td').click(function () {
    ths = $(this);
    color = $(this).css("backgroundColor");
    if (color == "rgb(240, 0, 0)") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
    } else {
        ths.css("background-color", "rgb(240, 0, 0)");
    }
})
})
```

the full code is here >> http://jsfiddle.net/Y8W78/4/

Comment: you are missing such unimportant part as application server...

Comment: jQuery is client side scripting and as such cant communicate directly with your database. By design, the database access is kept away from the client and you will need a service to act as the go-between. In this case you will need to create the relevant PHP file which connects to your database and others to support your querys. These files will need to return data back to the client from your aJax calls.

Comment: ok...so i need a php file to connect to my db and get my data....lets pretent i have that....how do i get the cells bgcolor red if i get the row and col from the db

Comment: @FoxWizzy Have you stored all td color values in DB?

Comment: @Jenson M John The color is red rgb(240, 0, 0)(no other color)...the row number and col number of a cell is inserted in the db when you click on a cell...i use php explode to separate the cells stored in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call webservice from jquery

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function getValue(row,col) {

        var param = "{'Variable1':" + JSON.stringify(row) + 
        ",'Variable2':" + JSON.stringify(col) + "}";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WSAccessMPJquery.asmx/getColor",
            data: param,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: onSucceed,
            error: onFailed
        });
    }
    function onSucceed(result) {
        alert("text from server: "+ result.d);
    }

    function onFailed() {
        alert('call failed');
    }
</script>
```

create web service in your app which will return color in string
I use this to call webservice in ASP.NET